# Not able to start Docker daemon

Tags: docker, centos, proxmox

I have installed docker in CentOS 7 and when I run

```
[root@hk-qa-linux-2 ~]# docker daemon
```

I get the following

```
    INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 611 
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded. 
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit 
WARN[0001] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts          
WARN[0001] Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts        
WARN[0001] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts       
WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found                
FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

When I checked my file mounts I could see cgroup

```
[root@hk-qa-linux-2 cgroup]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop6      61796348 689300  57944984   2% /
none                 100      0       100   0% /dev
cgroup                12      0        12   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            4032272      0   4032272   0% /sys/fs/cgroup/cgmanager
tmpfs            4032272      0   4032272   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4032272   8244   4024028   1% /run
tmpfs             104860      0    104860   0% /run/user/0
```

Not sure how to solve this issue. Any suggestion would be helpful

```
System details

[root@hk-qa-linux-2 ~]# cat /etc/system-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

[root@hk-qa-linux-2 ~]# uname -r
4.2.6-1-pve 

[root@hk-qa-linux-2 ~]# docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you attempt to start it as root? Seeing a different prompt that makes me suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, trying everything as root. I have updated my question

Comment: Maybe try `sudo service docker start` and `sudo service docker status` and check your logs: `tail -n 100 /var/log/messages`

Comment: Try debugging with `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`, `cat /proc/cgroups`, and `sudo /etc/init.d/cgconfig status`. If the last command fails, you can try `sudo yum install libcgroup`.